# How to enable Placeholder for Floating Input Field in react?

Tags: html, reactjs, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

bootstrap based  Floating input place holder value not able to change. wanted to show some text as default like placeholder & should   enable the placeholder/value area editable. Please help

https://codesandbox.io/s/floating-input-placeholder-zvzmq0

```
<div class="form-floating mb-3 ">
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control  "
          id="floatingInput"
          placeholder="Enter text here …"
          value={"Enter text here …"}
        />
        <label for="floatingInput">Email address</label>
      </div>
```

Comment: Arent you using react-bootstrap? Why dou you only use bootstrap classes and not react-bootstrap components? - https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/forms/floating-labels/

Comment: Even I used react-bootstrap, placeholder is not visible or if I added value then its visible but not editable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not intended to show placeholder, when using a floating label.

When no value is provided the label is displayed in the middle of the input and covers the space where a placeholder is normally shown. When value is provided label **floats** to the top corner of the input and below you can see your specified value.

[image]

Technically you need to provide a placeholder value, but it's not shown:

> A placeholder is required on each <Form.Control> as our method of
> CSS-only floating labels uses the :placeholder-shown pseudo-element.

https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/forms/floating-labels/

Here is a working codesanbox with floating labels and changeable value:
https://codesandbox.io/s/floating-input-placeholder-forked-3tvf50